# Solution for pipes and cistern question given below?

Tags: word-problem

Q.) Two pipes $P$ and $Q$ can fill a tank in $20$ hours and $25$ hours respectively while a third pipe $R$ can empty the tank in
$30$ hours. If all the pipes are opened together for $10$ hrs and then pipe $R$ is closed then in what time the tank can be filled.

Comment: $\frac {1 - 10(\frac {1}{20} + \frac {1}{25} - \frac {1}{30})}{\frac 1{20} + \frac {1}{25}}$

 What do you think each term represents?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can look at the rate at which they fill each tank as shown below:
$$W_P=\frac{1}{20},\,W_Q=\frac{1}{25},\,W_R=\frac{1}{30}$$
Now firstly we know that all three are open for $10$ hours together, meaning it will be filled by:
$$L=10\left(\frac1{20}+\frac1{25}+\frac1{30}\right)$$
And for the rest of the time, which we will call $t_1$, only $W_P$ and $W_Q$ can be applied. This means the remaining amount needing to be filled takes:
$$1-10\left(\frac1{20}+\frac1{25}+\frac1{30}\right)=t_1\left(\frac1{20}+\frac1{25}\right)$$
This can be rearranged to give:
$$t_1=\frac{1-10\left(\frac1{20}+\frac1{25}+\frac1{30}\right)}{\left(\frac1{20}+\frac1{25}\right)}$$
But in the total time we must allow for the 10 hours that have already passed, and so:
$$t=\frac{1-10\left(\frac1{20}+\frac1{25}+\frac1{30}\right)}{\left(\frac1{20}+\frac1{25}\right)}+10$$

Comment: I have written this answer since it is your first question, but next time try to show some attempt at working or at least your level of understanding for the problem

Comment: seems that you you took a drain as a .. filling !

Comment: It does say filling a tank right

Comment: .."while a third pipe is **empting** the tank "..

Comment: Oh damn yeah. I misread it as them all filling the tank

Comment: I think my answer remains the same but replace 1/30 with -1/30 everywhere

Comment: yes, that is, empting is the negative of filling, and assuming inflow and outflow are constant (which in practice is never met, but ok .. this is a math site !) your answer would be correct if amended in sign. So do that.

Comment: Can anyone show me how it is answered in efficiency method?

Comment: 20,25,30 - LCM= 300, EFFICIENCY=+15,+12,-10

Comment: 1hr - (15+12-10)= 17unit ; 10hr --170unit

Comment: T=W/E= (300-170)/15+12 = 130/27